# Reduce amount of or remove @Autowired annotations In Spring Junit 5 test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit5

Is it possible in Junit 5 to inject spring beans into test class without @Autowired annotation? My code look like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SomeApp.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class SomeTest {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService

    @Test
    public void shouldMakeMagic() { ....
```

and I would like to remove all @Autowired annotations

Comment: What do you want to achieve by removing those? Maybe you need mocking?

Comment: 99% of my test doesn't have mocks or mocks are defined as spring beans. This annotation is for me only boilerplate. In Kotlin works something like this: 

`class SomeTest @Autowired constructor( private val someService: SomeService ) {` and I would like to achieve something like this in java - inject by constructor without autowired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage in Kotlin is that you can declare member fields on constructor which you can not do in Java. In Java you can make `@Autowired` constructor but it would not reduce the boilerplate since you still would have to declare class members in the class.

But if you are willing to use the magical Java boilerplate code remover Project Lombok you could achieve something similar, see below example with comments:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
// Below will generate you the constuctor for each final member
// and add @Autowired on it so resulting:
// @Autowired
// public SomeTest(SomeService someService, SomeOtherService someOtherService)    
// {
//    this.someService = someServive;
//    this.someOtherService = someOtherServive;
// }
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}))
public class SomeTest {

    private final SomeService someService;
    private final SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    @Test
    public void shouldMakeMagic() {
        assertNotNull(someService);
        assertNotNull(someOtherService);
    }
    
}
```

Now the difference is that while Kotlin generates members from constructor automatically, Java & Lombok generate constructor from members.

**Note**: this of course applies also to main code not only tests.

Comment: With recent Spring versions, you can also remove `@Autowired` on the constructor if you just have one for your class. This will reduce the _boilerplate_ even more to just `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

Comment: @rieckpil Thanks for the tip. I will test that also. Typically in test class there is just that one constructor.

Comment: Without Autowired doesnt work RequiredArgsConstructor. I have: `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter`